# Why ASP.Net Site automatically Logout when Navigating to different pages in IE11?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-11

Deployed an ASP.Net site and the same is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, when logged into IE11 and navigated to few pages it automatically logged me out and redirected to login page. nothing is recorded in Log file to find the issue. didn't find the reason why its happening only in IE11.

Comment: Does it get logged out on a specific page? Are you trying to display iframe or navigating to some other site? Did you see any error or warning message in the console? your site is using an internet zone or intranet zone? Just for testing purposes, try to lower down the security levels to see whether it makes any difference. Please try to provide detailed information about your application. If possible post some code. It may help to understand the issue in a better way. the above description is not giving much idea about the cause of the issue.

Comment: Issue not occurred for a specific page, getting the issue while navigating to different pages at each time. didn't get any error logs in console or network. not accessing iframe or any other site. using sessionState in Custom mode in Web.config.

Comment: In your web.config file add cookieless="true" in sessionsstate tag and again try to test the issue. Let me know about the other information which I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: SessionState is Custom mode with cookieless="true" still issue exist. using Internet zone.

Comment: Can you provide any sample code to test this issue with IE 11? We will try to check the issue with the IE 11 browser and try to provide suggestions for it.